# window.removeEventListener is not removing event from window

Tags: javascript

Hi all i am simply trying to remove this keyup event from the window and it is not working.

```
  toggle(forceClose = false) {
    const shouldClose = forceClose || this.isOpen()
    const action = shouldClose ? 'remove' : 'add'
    const expanded = !shouldClose

    var escape = function(e) {
      if (e.key === "Escape" || e.which === 27) {
        console.log("Escape")
      }
    }

    if (shouldClose && this.targetEl) {
      window.removeEventListener('keyup', escape, true)
      this.targetEl.classList.remove(this.options.menuActiveClass)
      setTimeout(() => !this.targetEl.classList.contains(this.options.menuActiveClass) && this.targetEl.classList.remove(this.options.menuOpenClass), 300)
    } else if (this.targetEl) {
      window.addEventListener('keyup', escape, true)
      this.targetEl.classList.add(this.options.menuOpenClass)
      setTimeout(() => this.targetEl.classList.contains(this.options.menuOpenClass) && this.targetEl.classList.add(this.options.menuActiveClass), 10)
    }

  }
```

Comment: because escape is different each time you call toggle

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `escape` function on every call. So `removeEventListener` will try to remove something that never been added.

Move the declaration to the outer scope

```
  toggle(forceClose = false) {
    const shouldClose = forceClose || this.isOpen()
    const action = shouldClose ? 'remove' : 'add'
    const expanded = !shouldClose



    if (shouldClose && this.targetEl) {
      window.removeEventListener('keyup', escape, true)
      this.targetEl.classList.remove(this.options.menuActiveClass)
      setTimeout(() => !this.targetEl.classList.contains(this.options.menuActiveClass) && this.targetEl.classList.remove(this.options.menuOpenClass), 300)
    } else if (this.targetEl) {
      window.addEventListener('keyup', escape, true)
      this.targetEl.classList.add(this.options.menuOpenClass)
      setTimeout(() => this.targetEl.classList.contains(this.options.menuOpenClass) && this.targetEl.classList.add(this.options.menuActiveClass), 10)
    }

  }

function escape(e) {
  if (e.key === "Escape" || e.which === 27) {
    console.log("Escape")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call removeEventListener you have to pass as function the same instance passing on addEventListener.

So in your case you have to define escape ouside toggle